# взаимодействие с переменными из другого case

Tags: c#

Есть кусок кода, где в case2 создается одномерный массив, а в case3 нужно вывести созданный ранее массив. Проблема заключается в том, что из case2 не удается получить доступ к переменным case1.

```
case 2:
    Console.WriteLine("Введите количество элементов");
    strings = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    table = new int[strings];
    Console.WriteLine();

    for (i = 0; i < strings; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите элемент: " + Convert.ToInt32(i + 1));
        table[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    break;
case 3:
    foreach (int x in table)
    {
        Console.Write(x + " ");
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Знаете что такое глобальная и локальная переменная? Вот вам это и нужно. Сделайте изменяемый вами объект за пределами `switch` и работайте с ними.

Comment: почитай про область видимости переменных

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.